# How can i authorize my jwt token in postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I have created my protected routes and i will like to access the protected routes using jwt token from postman

Answer (score 1):

One way to get around this is this:

1. Store JWT in session/cookie for the user.
2. Send this as a request header. You can call it `x-api-token` or whatever you like.
3. Keep the public key for JWT in server's environment or file-system.
4. Read the value of header i.e. `x-api-key`
5. Verify using any JWT library to make sure it's authentic.